# floating div not on top of page

Tags: css, html, floating

I've got three left-floating div (1, 2 & 3) and one floating right (4), which is also the last div in my HTML code. The three on the left take up 60% of the width and the last div should fill in on the right. However div 4 only floats past the div 3 and then stops.

```
<body>
    <div style="width: 60%; float: left; background-color: red;">
        div 1
    </div>
    <div style="width: 60%; float: left; background-color: red;">
        div 2
    </div>
    <div style="width: 60%; float: left; background-color: red;">
        div 3
    </div>
    <div style="width: 40%; float: right; background-color: yellow;">
        div 4
    </div>
</body>
```

Any suggestions how to make the div go to the top of the page?

Comment: some code will be good

Comment: Second @MoathHowari: help us [reproduce](http://sscce.org) your issue (note: you can edit your question to add code to it).

Comment: Wild guess: perhaps you're experiencing the difference between [standard box-sizing](http://jsfiddle.net/m4duE/) and [border-box sizing](http://jsfiddle.net/fyyMV/)?

Comment: Thanks posted some code.

Comment: You mean 60% of 100% by summing all left floated dividers or each of them 60%? because right now it shows there are 3 dividers that each would take 60% of upper row and there would be no space for either div 3 or div 4 on that row anymore because both div 1 and 2 would exceed 100%. I think you should replace 60% with 20% after that they're all going to fit.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9Yck/2/)

I edited a bit your HTML code:

```
<section class="container">
    <div class="block one"></div>
    <div class="block two"></div>
    <div class="block three"></div>
    <div class="block four"></div>
</section>
```

Just add these CSS rules:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, div, section {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body {
    background: #CCC;
    height: 100%;
}
.block {
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.block:not(.four) {
    float: left;
    width: calc(60% / 3);
}
.four {
    width: calc(100% - 60%);
}
.container > .four {
    float: right;
}
```

I used the `calc()` function for set the anchors to the elements. You can see the browser support [here](http://caniuse.com/calc)

**EDIT** Sorry, I didn't understand your question. This is what you want! [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9Yck/3/) =)

Cheers,
Leo!

Comment: What I want is this: http://jsfiddle.net/SM68h/
Except the yellow div should be on the top of the page (next to div 1) rather than next to div 3

Comment: But in that fiddle the four block isn't in the top O.o. If I read well, you want to put the four element on to the top (like in my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9Yck/2/)), not?

Comment: yes but the div 1, 2 and 3 should be one below each other rather than next to each other. Div 1, 2 & 3 will be the main content of my page and div 4 will be a sidebar.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for! But is there no easier way? Do floating divs by default just float past one div or why does it not go higher up?

Comment: Far as I know, you can't (if you want to use the `float` property).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve here is put some `content` in your page (the left floated divs) and a `sidebar` (the right div).
Well, there are many ways to do it, here is a method `without using floats` (right or left).

HTML:

```
<body>
    <section style="width: 60%;"> <!-- Your main content goes in here -->
        <div style="background-color: red;">div 1</div>
        <div style="background-color: red;">div 2</div>
        <div style="background-color: red;">div 3</div>
    </section>
    <aside style="width: 40%;" class="right"> <!-- content for right sidebar -->
        <div style="background-color: yellow;">div 4</div>
    </aside>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
aside,section {
    display : inline-block;
    padding : 0;
    margin : 0;
}

aside.right {
    vertical-align: top; //to bring sidebar to top
}
```

Here is a demo [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kQ6S6/)

Comment: Add `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` to your example and you'll be able to put the second `aside` to 40% (in the `width` property) ;).

Comment: @LeonardoManrique that didn't work either,, here is the updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kQ6S6/1/ Been scratching my head, how to get it right, a newbie at jsfiddle :-/